# Flutter wont run after SDK update

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I recently needed cloned a project off of github after I had updated my flutter sdk and had to run pub get and it indicated that i needed to migrate based on instructions from this link  (https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration) which i have managed to do ,
the problem becomes that when I run flutter, I get the following error

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\Clima-Flutter\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-28:19: AAPT: error: resource style/NormalTheme (aka co.appbrewery.clima:style/NormalTheme) not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

and when i use flutter verbose I get these

```
C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\Clima-Flutter>flutter run --verbose
[ +130 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +62 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] f30b7f4db93ee747cd727df747941a28ead25ff5
[        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git tag --points-at HEAD
[  +52 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at HEAD
[        ] 1.22.0-12.4.pre
           1.22.1
[  +10 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +47 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +44 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +93 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +50 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[ +101 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +11 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +7 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +7 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +33 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +38 ms] executing: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +80 ms] List of devices attached
           043911194R100252       device product:H624 model:Infinix_X627 device:Infinix-X627STU transport_id:1
[  +11 ms] C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 043911194R100252 shell getprop
[ +164 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +370 ms] Generating C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\Clima-Flutter\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +30 ms] ro.hardware = mt6761
[   +1 ms] ro.build.characteristics = default
[  +54 ms] Starting incremental build...
[   +3 ms] Initializing file store
[  +12 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[   +8 ms] complete
[   +7 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on Infinix X627 in debug mode...
[   +8 ms] C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names --experimental-emit-debug-metadata
-Ddart.developer.causal_async_stacks=true --output-dill C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.7acea879\flutter_tool.7d1d5a82\app.dill --packages .packages
-Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false
--bytecode-options=source-positions,local-var-info,debugger-stops,instance-field-initializers,keep-unreachable-code,avoid-closure-call-instructions --enable-asserts
--track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill build\cache.dill.track.dill
[  +28 ms] executing: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 043911194R100252 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +98 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 043911194R100252 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[        ] --------- beginning of main
           11-24 15:22:59.002 I/SurfaceFlinger(  412): [Built-in Screen (type:0)] fps:3.953414,dur:1011.78,max:629.23,min:16.35
[   +1 ms] executing: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 043911194R100252 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +97 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 043911194R100252 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[        ] --------- beginning of main
           11-24 15:22:59.378 I/ADB_SERVICES( 1616): post waitpid (pid=17140) status=0000
[  +21 ms] <- compile package:clima/main.dart
[  +32 ms] executing: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[ +156 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
                    Version 30.0.4-6686687
                    Installed as C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[   +6 ms] executing: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[ +158 ms] Building APK
[  +46 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[  +91 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[  +15 ms] Using gradle from C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\Clima-Flutter\android\gradlew.bat.
[   +3 ms] C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\Clima-Flutter\android\gradlew.bat mode: 33279 rwxrwxrwx.
[  +16 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[ +208 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_242-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b01, mixed mode)
[   +4 ms] executing: [C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\Clima-Flutter\android/] C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\Clima-Flutter\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true
-Ptarget-platform=android-arm -Ptarget=C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\Clima-Flutter\lib\main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[+1032 ms] Welcome to Gradle 5.4.1!
[   +1 ms] Here are the highlights of this release:
[   +1 ms]  - Run builds with JDK12
[   +1 ms]  - New API for Incremental Tasks
[        ]  - Updates to native projects, including Swift 5 support
[   +1 ms] For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/release-notes.html
[+4112 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
[  +91 ms] [ +180 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +42 ms] [  +91 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +87 ms] [        ] f30b7f4db93ee747cd727df747941a28ead25ff5
[  +22 ms] [   +5 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git tag --points-at HEAD
[   +3 ms] [  +58 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at HEAD
[   +1 ms] [        ] 1.22.0-12.4.pre
[   +2 ms]            1.22.1
[   +1 ms] [  +15 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +2 ms] [  +58 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +1 ms] [        ] origin/stable
[   +1 ms] [        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +1 ms] [  +47 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +1 ms] [        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +107 ms] [ +114 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +3 ms] [ +167 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +2 ms] [        ] stable
[   +1 ms] [  +85 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +9 ms] [   +6 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] [  +27 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +6 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[  +33 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +16 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +6 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +46 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +17 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +13 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [ +155 ms] Initializing file store
[   +1 ms] [  +39 ms] Done initializing file store
[  +79 ms] [  +82 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[+1099 ms] [+1139 ms] Skipping target: kernel_snapshot
[   +1 ms] [  +12 ms] invalidated build due to missing files: C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\Clima-Flutter\DOES_NOT_EXIST_RERUN_FOR_WILDCARD208953078
[ +699 ms] [ +691 ms] debug_android_application: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputMissing}
[ +299 ms] [ +275 ms] Manifest contained wildcard assets. Inserting missing file into build graph to force rerun. for more information see #56466.
[        ] [  +48 ms] debug_android_application: Complete
[ +600 ms] [ +534 ms] Persisting file store
[   +2 ms] [  +18 ms] Done persisting file store
[   +1 ms] [   +8 ms] build succeeded.
[        ] [  +18 ms] "flutter assemble" took 3,103ms.
[        ] [   +5 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 0ms
[        ] [   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] [   +5 ms] exiting with code 0
[ +399 ms] > Task :app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[   +2 ms] > Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[   +2 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[   +2 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[  +79 ms] > Task :app:cleanMergeDebugAssets
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
[ +412 ms] > Task :app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug
[  +12 ms] > Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[  +71 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[  +12 ms] > Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[ +489 ms] > Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
[   +2 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +3 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
[        ] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
[        ]    > Android resource linking failed
[        ]      C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\Clima-Flutter\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-28:19: AAPT: error: resource style/NormalTheme (aka
co.appbrewery.clima:style/NormalTheme) not found.
[   +1 ms] * Try:
[   +1 ms] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 9s
[        ] 16 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 11 up-to-date
[ +653 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 10.9s)
[+1536 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 14,127ms.
[   +6 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:607:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:977:18)
           #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
           #12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #18     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #19     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #20     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
           #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #23     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #26     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #27     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #34     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

I cant seem to understand it considering that all other app seem to run well since the update

Comment: Angela Yu, Flutter course?
One suggestion though, never upgrade Flutter through the command line, always download the zip file and use that. I have broken my projects many times because of that..

Comment: @KetanRamteke is there any fix for that??

Answer (score 2):

In my case, updating Gradle worked.
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin